# How to add dummy data to datatable in django?

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-templates, django-datatable

I have done one small application in **django**.For **datatables**, I have used 
from `django_datatables_view.base_datatable_view import BaseDatatableView  import` .For this datatable,it will show results directly from **queryset**.
Now my requirement is to add some dummy data to that **queryset** ( want to show some dummy data in view )

Comment: You can try django-autofixture, please also look into other ones here:https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/fixtures/

Answer (score 0):

You can try django-autofixture, please also look into other ones [here](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/fixtures/).

Comment: this is looks like a comment not answer.